# Create a new file for a known shell type in windows using C#

Tags: c#, windows, shell

Windows shell allows to associate a file type with a certain application through its extension. This association often provides `ShellNew` command, which allows to create a new file of a given type with a default template provided by an application. When you select `New` in context menu of windows explorer it offers a selection of different file types, which can be created this way. I want to implement this action from my C# application.

It is trivial to open an existing file as follows.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = 
  new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(path);
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```

If you pass any valid path of an existing file with an extension registered for shell "Open" command, it will open a given file in its default application.
For instance, pass `path = "text.txt"` and Notepad will open "text.txt" for you.

However, I cannot find a code to create new file in a similar manner.

For instance, Microsoft Word is a registered application for "New" command. I can create new MS Word document with a default template directly from windows explorer without opening MS Word. I want to do exactly same from my C# application: create new MS Word file without linking to MS Word automation.

I m sure that it is possible to do for any file type properly registered for "New" command in windows shell. But strangely, this topic is not covered in all standard searches I ve tried.

### Proposed solution

After despairing to find any ready code snippet, I've composed this function to extract the info from registry. It gets a file extension from requested full path to new file. Then it finds associated class info for given extension and extracts "FileName" value from "ShellNew" subkey. Finally, it copies a template from the path found in registry to desired destingation of new file.

```
public static bool CreateFileOfKnownType(string path)
{
  try
  {
    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension)) return false;

    using (var rExt = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension))
    {
      string[] apps = rExt.GetSubKeyNames();
      foreach (string app in apps)
      {
        if (app.Contains("."))
        {
          string shellNew = apps[0] + "\\ShellNew";
          using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rApp = rExt.OpenSubKey(shellNew))
          {
            string newFileTemplate = rApp.GetValue("FileName").ToString();
            System.IO.File.Copy(newFileTemplate, path);
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  catch { return false; }
}
```

This code works fine in some cases when "FileName" contains full path to application template. However, in other cases "FileName" contains only file name of the template without full path. Then this code fails. If somebody knows an improvement, which will work universally, it will be very appreciated.

Comment: Provided an additional info in question to sound more precisely due to some confusion revealed in previous discussion.

Comment: I have found a useful info here. It describes how to get a list of all file extensions eligible for "New" command:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a4c0e34-04d8-4ccb-8e98-9ba983e126f8/shellnew?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: this info doesn't actual for Win11 :(

Answer (score -1):

You would need to be manipulating the registry to create these associations - typically this is done as part of the software installation process.

More information on how to create the registry keys at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/cc144156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I consider this answer off topic. Question is not on how to create a file association for a given extension. Question is about how to use an existing association to create a new file. Thank you.

Comment: The question is: How to use my C# application in the "New" context menu within the Windows Shell?

The answer: You have to edit the registry so that the "New" action within the File Association registry points to your C# application.

My answer is not wrong - you just don't know how Windows works!

Comment: Sorry, not. I have no plan using my application as a target of "New" command in windows shell. Just to the opposite, I want to use my application to invoke other application already registered for "New" command in shell to create proper files for me. I m sorry, if question is formulated vague. But I read it again and did not find and word hinting to the opposite. For instance, MS Word is a registered application for "New" command. I can create new MS Word document with a default template directly from windows explorer without opening MS Word. I want to do exactly same from my C# application.